# Stringing CmdExe commands for SQL Job

Tags: cmd, sql-job

I am working on a simple CmdExe action to run as part of a nightly SQL job.  The job's core function is that it creates an exported txt file to a folder to be accessed by our partner via ftp.  We want to have the job move any files in the folder to a backup location before creating the new file.  I have done a simple move command such as the one below as a starter:

```
MOVE "\\Server1\e$\FTPFolder\1234.TXT" "\\Server1\e$\Backup\"
```

This command works fine.  However, since this a test environment and needs to be done to several jobs now as well as to be moved to production I was hoping to format this with a variable so that I can could easily change the Server name context.  From my search the proper syntax should be like this:

```
SET location=Server1 && MOVE "\\%location%\e$\FTPFolder\1234.TXT" "\\%location%\e$\Backup\"
```

however, executing this with the job fails and testing with cmd returns "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect".  However, if I break them off in cmd by setting the variable first, hit enter, and then create the same Move command it works.  Is there something I'm missing that needs to be done to strings these together correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Cmd evaluates the whole line before running it. So it goes to:

```
SET location=Server1 && MOVE "\\\e$\FTPFolder\1234.TXT" "\\\e$\Backup\"
```

because when it evaluated %location% was not defined. To tell him to evaluate on runtime, replace % with ! (help set)
    SET location=Server1 && MOVE "\!location!\e$\FTPFolder\1234.TXT" "\!location!\e$\Backup\"